# Java Casting query Exception and error

Tags: java, casting

In java when do we get a incompatible type compilation error and when do we get a ClassCastException?

Comment: Search on google, SO is not here to explain the concepts.

Comment: Please Java docs and you will get the answer.

Comment: usually the ClassCastException is a runtime error. Incompatible types are usually checked at the compile time for your code.

Answer (score 1):

[ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) API Specifications clearly says:

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a
>   subclass of which it is not an instance.

ClassCastException occurs at runtime because compiler believes that the cast may be a valid one.

Eg:

```
// The below line will compile but ClassCastException will be raised at runtime
Integer i = (Integer) new Object();
```

Incompatible type error can easily be resolved by the compiler at compile time itself. It simply looks if the class to which you are trying to cast a specific object falls in the same hierarchy.

Eg:

```
 String str = "abc"; <br>Integer number = (Integer) str;  
// Compile Error :  Integer and String are not in the same hierarchy
```